# CKEditor: is it possible to make img inline editable with contenteditable="true"

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I'm trying to get CKEditor up and running with [Inline Editing](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline), and I want to allow users to only edit single dom elements like h1, h2, p, ect. and it's working fine - but I can't get it to work for html img element:

```
<img src="img/myimage.jpg" contenteditable="true" />
```

Images are working fine if I allow CKEditor to insert images into eg. a div element, but is there a way to only allow the content editor to update the src for img tag?

**UPDATE**

I have solved this with simple jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img[contenteditable]').click(function (event) {
    var view = $(event.target);

    var uniqueIdforCurrentElement = randomString(32).trim();
    if (view.attr('id') === undefined || view.attr('id') === '') {
        view.attr('id', uniqueIdforCurrentElement);
    } else {
         uniqueIdforCurrentElement = view.attr('id');
    }
    window.open('mySelectImageUrl' + 
                   '?mode=jquery" + 
                   '&CKEditorFuncNum=' + uniqueIdforCurrentElement, 
                   'imageWindow', 
                   'width=800, height=600');
    });
});
```

and in imageWindow:

```
var element = window.opener.document.getElementById('<%:Model.Callback%>');
element.src = fileUrl;
```